# How to block some disks from probes on Linux boot?

Tags: storage-area-network, boot, scsi, fibre-channel, multipath

My linux host connected to SAN with FC interface. 
It connect with one path, and see some luns, that can't access, because they need anohter path, not available to host.

On boot linux probe all lun he can see, get read error on unaccessible luns, and hangs there for a long-long time.

Is there a way to disable any access to some luns at boot time, and later?

I found a filters for device ignoration for LVM and MULTIPATH, but it not help during boot process.

Generally, lvm still affected too despite of filter, and gives me a IO error on every operation like lvdisplay and vgdisplay, but this is another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually accomplished with LUN masking (usually on the array) or some combination of zoning and/or VSAN's on the switch (depending on vendor, topology, etc).  Generally it's not a great idea to expose all of your LUN's to all of your hosts.

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle drop suport immediately after SUN acquiration to my ST2540 disk arrays, and it's impossible to buy licenses to security domains :( . It means I can't hide luns from servers.

Comment: What about the FC switch itself?  Do you have access to it and, if so, can you tell us which model it might be?

Comment: It's kind of HP, but there I can manage only host-array, not host-ln permissions. I can't hide any lun in case I should represent at least one lun from array.

Comment: HP doesn't make its own switches, and whatever switch it is will let you perform zoning if you can get admin access to it.

Comment: Switch manufactured by Brocade. I can completely hide disk array from server by setting zones on switch. I can't hide some LUNs but present some other from same disk array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing LUNs on a server that it doesn't need, you must adjust the LUN masking on the storage device. All HP storage devices that use LUNs allow for LUN masking. If you provide the model, we can probably look up a guide.

That said, the LUN masking is really done on the storage, not the switch. The switch manages which physical ports your server can see, not which LUNs get reported to its world wide name.

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle drop suport immediately after SUN acquiration to my ST2540 disk arrays, and it's impossible to buy licenses to security domains.

Comment: If you can't find licenses on ebay or whatever, you'll need to replace the storage to fix the problem.